# Importing local packages shows 'cannot find path' error

Tags: android, flutter

I'm working on a Flutter project, I have color.dart at the location indicated in the dir structure below, in this color.dart I have import statement

```
import 'package:mbcl/src/level_item.dart';
```

where the level_item.dart is located again indicated below. I am running in to the error

```
lib/color.dart:8:8: Error: Error when reading '../lib/mbcl/lib/src/level_item.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:mbcl/src/level_item.dart'; `
```

Here's my directory structure:

```
mathebuddy
├── app
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── color.dart
│   ├── pubspec.yaml
│   └── ...
├── lib
│   ├── mbcl
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── level_item.dart
│       ├── pubspec.yaml
└── ...
```

I was expecting the import to work smoothly, but I'm encountering an error in the import statement, and I'm having difficulty pinpointing the exact issue.